# Stability Condition of System of ODE's and its Adjoint

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

Consider the linear ODE system and it's adjoint version given by (1) and (2) respectively.

$$x'(t)=M(t)x(t) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)$$

$$y'(t)=-M^*(t)y(t) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (2)$$

where $M$ is an $n\times n$ matrix and $M^*$ it's adjoint (conjugate transpose). Here $x(t),y(t)\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Further let $X(t)$ be a fundamental matrix of (1) such that there exists a constant $K$ such that $|X(t)|\leq K$ for $t\geq 0$ (*).

Show (2) satisfies the above property (*) if and only if

$$\liminf_{t\to \infty} \int_0^t tr(M(\tau))d\tau\neq -\infty$$

I am unsure how to relate the stability of a linear system of ODE's to that of its trace. Perhaps the Abel-Liouville-Jacobi Formula may be of help which states that if $X(t)$ is a fundamental matrix of (1), then $\det(X(t))=det(X(t_0))e^{\int_{t_0}^t tr(M(\tau))d\tau}$. A hint in the right direction would be much appreciated, since I am unsure how to proceed at the moment. Thank you in advance!

Comment: The adjoint is constructed in such a way that $y(t)^*x(t)=y(0)^*x(0)=const.$ So when $x$ converges to zero, then $y$ has to diverge. The only way for $y$ to stay bounded is for $x$ to stay bounded away from zero. The trace condition expresses this, it enforces that $x$ becomes stationary without converging to zero, that $M$ becomes traceless faster than $x$ moves towards the origin. In turn, the divergence of $y$ gets arrested at some finite position.

Answer (score 1):

First, You can represent $Y(t)$ in terms of $X(t)$ with some basic techniques(Cramer's rule) in linear algebra. Next, using the given condition that the $\liminf$ term is not $-\infty$, you can say that the $\det X(t)$ (in the Liouville's formula) is bounded away from $0$ for all time.